# new post-type how do i retain the plugins on my sidebar?

Tags: custom-post-types, functions

I created a new post-type following this technique: (http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-use-custom-post-types/)

After creating a a new post-type some of the feature of the a regular post also disappeared. I installed a plugin (SEO Pressor) that helps my seo on creating a new post. That plugin can be seen in the sidebar when you create a new post, Together with "Publish", "Categories" etc.. . currently the new post-type only contains the "Publish" and "Attributes" block.

Any idea how I can call those plugin to my new post-type?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plugin would need to support custom post types. You might be able to ask the plugin developer to add that. The custom post type API's are fairly new and still don't have widespread support.

You can see that they are adding the meta boxes only for posts and pages:

```
add_meta_box( 'WPPostsRateKeys-Keyword', 'SEOPressor Keyword', array(&$this,'add_box_in_post_form'), 'post', 'normal', 'high' );     
add_meta_box( 'WPPostsRateKeys-Keyword', 'SEOPressor Keyword', array(&$this,'add_box_in_post_form'), 'page', 'normal', 'high' );
add_meta_box( 'seo_pressor_post_suggestions', 'SEOPressor Score', array(&$this, 'show_score_box'), 'page', 'side', 'high' );             
add_meta_box( 'seo_pressor_post_suggestions', 'SEOPressor Score', array(&$this, 'show_score_box'), 'post', 'side', 'high' );
```

But without knowing how much they rely on the different post types it's hard to say how easy it would be to add those meta boxes to custom post types.

Comment: I'm wondering if theirs other way around this... I already posted a ticket in seopressor. I hope there's a solution on this.. thanks!